# Set or change default text in hyperlink popup in post editor

Tags: html-editor

When writing a post or page in the post editor (not the Visual editor but the HTML editor) and clicking on the "link" button, a popup appears with `http://` already prefilled.

Is there a way to change this default text?

For example, since I usually link internally to my own site I would want to use my base URL because then I could either quickly type the rest of the URL, or just overwrite it if I was hyperlinking somewhere else.

`http://www.myurl.com/`

I swear I saw a blog article on how to do this but I cannot locate it through searching the web.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try hacking into wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/js/wplink.js

and change:

- `if(!i.href||i.href=="http://")` (two times)
- `b.url.val("http://`

Comment: Is there any way to do it by editing quicktags.js? I went through the file but it wasn't obvious.

Comment: i don't think quicktags.js has anything to do with this. Editing wplink.js shouldn't be so hard, though: just do find&replace 'http://' to 'http://www.myurl.com' 3 times and you're done...